# Database encryption where key can be provided in connection string

Tags: mysql, encryption

I have certain information being stored in a MySQL database that warrants being stored in an encrypted form. However my .Net application can't absorb the perfomance hit of doing the encryption and decryption at the application layer.

Is there any MySQL function that allows an ecryption key to be specified in the connection string and then have the MySQL database do the encrption operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean

[AES_ENCRYPT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt)

and

[AES_DECRYPT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-decrypt)

you can pass the key when you run the query

you can see an [example](http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/encrypt-mysql-data-using-aes-techniques/)

EDIT:

another option to use

[DES_ENCRYPT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_des-encrypt) and DES_DECRYPT()

The key file can be specified with the `--des-key-file` server option

Comment: That pointed me in the right dirn. What I actually want is Transparent Data Encryption (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparent_Data_Encryption). But appears I'm out of luck with MySQL unless I want to purchase a commercial product at $50/month!